# Customize RNPickerSelect Style in expo reacte

Tags: expo, background

I am working on a project that utilizes the Expo framework. I have encountered an issue related to the styling of the RNPickerSelect component within my application.

The problem I am facing is that, when using the RNPickerSelect component, I am unable to see the items due to what appears to be a background and text color issue. The background and item color seem to be set to white, making the items invisible to the user.

I have reviewed the documentation for RNPickerSelect and have attempted various styling configurations without success.
How can I fix this problem !!?